# A possible refinement of a theorem of Malliavin

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, lie-groups

Due to a theorem of Malliavin (an improvement of an erlier theorem of Dixmier and Malliavin, see [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/research/pdf/Dixmier-Malliavin.pdf)) we know that every compactly supported smooth function $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$ can be written as a sum of two convolutions
$$f=u_1\circ v_1+u_2\circ v_2$$
where the $u_i,v_i$ are smooth.

**Question:** Is it known whether we can choose the $u_i,v_i$ to vary continuously with $f$?

The original theorem By Dixmier and Malliavin proves that $f$ is the sum of finitely many convolutions (I believe they prove that $2^n$ is enough). In this case we can choose the functions to depend continuously on $f$, as is proved in [this undergraduate thesis](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~ums/pdf/alexthesis.pdf).

Malliavin's improvement of the theorem appears in "$C^{\infty}$ parametrix on Lie groups and two steps factorization on convolution algebras",  Harmonic analysis (Proc. Conf., Univ. Crete, Iraklion, 1978), pp. 142–156, Lecture Notes in Math., 781, Springer, Berlin, 1980.

Comment: I changed the two-letter prefixed tag you created, presumably in error, to the IMO intended one. 

Comment: Thanks quid! The tag suggestion doesn't work for me, for some reason, and I tagged it by mistake.

Comment: What can be done for a sum of two convolution products, but isn't possible with a finite sum?

Comment: Marc, are you asking for motivation for my question or Malliavin's theorem?

Comment: At first sight it seems to me that in  Sotirov's thesis only *sequential* continuity is considered. Since $\mathscr D(\mathbb R^n)$ is very far from being metrizable this can be much weaker than contiunity.